# Is there a ticket system that also does project management?

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, ticket-system

Were looking to roll out a ticket system that also has project management capability. We're currently using Trac but we find that it's really difficult to config and also has very weak support with workflows. Ideally we want a system that has:

- A ticket system that supports workflow
- Integrates well with window's Active Directory for user management
- Has good integration with our source management (SVN)
- Has project management functions and reporting. At the very least some sort of Gantt chart.
- Project manager needs to be able to pick tickets and features to go into a certain milestone/sprint
- The interface to this system needs to be accessible from any platform (windows, mac etc).

What system should we use? What are your experiences? We are looking at a few examples like Jira, FogBugz, TFS, Jass, etc etc. There's just too many, looking for recommendations.

We are a commercial shop so cost is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I find the Atlassian products to be affordable, robust, and well supported, so I went with [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) when I was looking at ticketing systems in the past.  It integrates nicely with AD and SVN which I had no trouble setting up.
One of the reasons I picked JIRA was the reporting functionality which gave great breakdowns of number of issues and progress on each project, and even let you use sql-like syntax to customize as needed.
It's web based, so any platform is not an issue.

I did not use it for project management, but they have a solid plugin community and a quick google search turns up a few gantt plugins such as [Gantt Connector](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/20871).

Answer (score 3):

I think [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) (opensource, GPL) is a nice alternative.

Below are some of the main features of Redmine (from the site).

- Multiple projects support
- Flexible role based access control
- Flexible issue tracking system
- Gantt chart and calendar
- News, documents & files management
- Feeds & email notifications
- Per project wiki
- Per project forums
- Time tracking
- Custom fields for issues, time-entries, projects and users
- SCM integration (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs)
- Issue creation via email
- Multiple LDAP authentication support
- User self-registration support
- Multilanguage support
- Multiple databases support

I'd also note:

- There are many [plugins for Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) on internet
- Issue reports generation in PDF
- Intuitive interface

Comment: It also supports flexible workflows, subtasking, subprojects etc.

Comment: I've also been working several years with Redmine and really liked it. The integrated Gantt view was indeed of great help to follow project progress.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the Redmine suggestion - it's got great functionality compared to the rest of the open-source/free competition, although in my opinion its still a relatively immature and unpolished product.

If you have your own servers or high end VPS, somebody dedicated to IT/admin stuff and don't mind paying the money, I think the Atlassian suite of tools (Jira etc.) are the way to go in terms of features, usability and customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can add my favourite to your short-list: [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) by CounterSoft.

It's .NET based and just requires Windows IIS/SQL Server, works on all browsers (even for some our client's running IE6 and keeps the MAC boys happy!).

Doesn't have AD support yet, but has fairly flexible capabilities to help you set it up so you get quickly user adoption. By this I mean, define your screens, tweak your on-screen labels, workflows, per-project metadata, nested versions (for your sprints, etc.).

Funnily enough, one thing that it has that really makes a difference to us is inline editing: editing in place when viewing lists of issues, makes things easier when running daily meetings, etc. Reporting is basic, but we dropped in our own custom reports (by creating simple ASP.NET User Controls).

We used it with SVN and it's OK but now switched to TFS Source Control and Gemini still works well with it.

Comment: We ditched Trac and went with Gemini -- works well for our general project needs as well as our software dev

Answer (score 0):

Please try BootStrapToday, it is just fit for your perusal. Equipped with all the features of Ticketing, Tracking, Project Management, SVN and GIT support, Integration with other softwares, Gantt charts, apart from these.. the Two very unique features of this tool are:

1) Automation :

2) Intelligence:

To gain insights of these features in detail do visit www.bootstraptoday.com

I have tried this tool at my office and the collaboration has become much more easier at our premises. 
BootStrapToday is also available as On-Premise set up as well cloud based.